# Output value of type A as result

Tags: scala, zio

I have next code in IDEA (scala workshop),

```
import zio.console.Console
import zio.{IO, Task, ZIO}

val st :Seq[Task[Int]] = Seq(Task(1),Task(2),Task(3))

val t : Task[List[Int]]= IO.collectAll(st)

val r : ZIO[Console, Throwable, List[Int]] = t

r.fold(
  f => {
    println(s"fail f=$f");
    0
  },
  s => {
    println(s"success res = ${s.sum}");
    1
  }
)
```

Could you help me pleas with output result (expected 6)

I have output

```
st: Seq[zio.Task[Int]] = List(zio.ZIO$EffectPartial@263c8be8, zio.ZIO$EffectPartial@469dccd5, zio.ZIO$EffectPartial@1a56563e)

t: zio.Task[List[Int]] = zio.ZIO$FlatMap@1e8d80f2
r: zio.ZIO[zio.console.Console,Throwable,List[Int]] = zio.ZIO$FlatMap@1e8d80f2

res0: zio.ZIO[zio.console.Console,Nothing,Int] = <function1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Method `fold` in `zio.ZIO` ([link](https://github.com/zio/zio/blob/v1.0.0-RC16/core/shared/src/main/scala/zio/ZIO.scala#L421)) is defined as:

```
final def fold[B](failure: E => B, success: A => B): ZIO[R, Nothing, B]
```

This signature shows that the method returns exactly the type you received, `zio.ZIO[zio.console.Console, Nothing, Int]`.

You can run the effect on a default runtime like this:

```
import zio.DefaultRuntime

val runtime = new DefaultRuntime {}

runtime.unsafeRun(effect)
```

Above code prints out "success res = 6".

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, all operations with ZIO including `collectAll` and `fold` are operations on functions, because each ZIO is basically a whimsical function by its nature. In your case `ZIO[Console, Throwable, List[Int]]` is a function where `Console` is an input parameter, and `Throwable`/`List[Int]` is one of two possible types of output. When you use combinators like `collectAll` and `fold` you basically construct a new function based on other functions.

The next step is to evaluate this new function by passing input parameter into it. In your case this input parameter is any trait that extends `Console` type. As @slouc reflected in his answer, you can just use `DefaultRuntime` "runner" on your `res0`, because default environment (input parameter in terms of functions) provided by this runner implements `Console` trait.

```
import zio.DefaultRuntime

val runtime = new DefaultRuntime {}

runtime.unsafeRun(res0)
```

There is another more explicit way to provide this Env by using ZIO#provide, but you will still need some runtime to execute this function after that.

I also want to note, that when you do `println` inside your `fold`, you don't actually use `Console` trait that you provide as input parameter, but you use regular `println` provided by native scala instead. In you basic case it doesn't matter, but on real applications you would need to use `putStrLn` provided by `Console`.